# Python package import issues

Tags: python-2.7

I am building a package that I want to be able to install with pip. The package name is 'pololu-motors' and is on PyPi now at version 0.1.2, but it seems to not import correctly.

**Update:** *The problem has been solved, the problem was **me** not the code, however I have updated the [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pololu-motors) to version 0.2.1 and made it more difficult to clobber the namespace, so hopefully nobody else will have the issue I had.*

If I cd into my virtual environment to the base of the `motors` module and import the package with ipython it works fine, but if I try to import the package from a test project, I've setup, it says it cannot file any of the classes that are on `motors`.

Here is my `motors/__init__.py`

```
from .qik2s9v1 import Qik2s9v1
```

Just outside of the motors module in site-packages:

```
In [1]: from motors import Qik2s9v1

In [2]:
```

There are no errors and the Qik2s9v1 class is found properly, however, in the test project I get this:

```
In [1]: from motors import Qik2s9v1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-79017388c348> in <module>()
----> 1 from motors import Qik2s9v1

ImportError: cannot import name Qik2s9v1
```

I can `import motors` with no errors, but the class `Qik2s9v1` is nowhere to be found.

```
In [2]: import motors

In [3]: motors.Qik2s9v1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fee4c340a836> in <module>()
----> 1 motors.Qik2s9v1

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Qik2s9v1'
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Please show all the files in your test project: is there perhaps another `motors.py` file around? Or perhaps such a `motors.py` file is somewhere else on your `PYTHONPATH`? Try `import motors; print motors.__file__` and see what that gives.

Comment: You were exactly correct, I have a `motors` directory in my test package that was clobbering my package name. I should probably make the import name of my package something less ambiguous than `motors`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Evert had the correct answer to this issue. As it turns out I had a directory named `motors` in the same location I was trying to import my package name `motors` with ipython. If I changed directory to any other place in my test package it would have worked just fine.

This is a stupid mistake that I shouldn't have made, but a lesson well learned.